# Error! in deploying rails in heroku ..

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When I try to deploy my app in heroku I got this error. I don't know why because last time I deploy my small app there's no error like this.

```
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: operator (>) (line: 47282, col: 30, pos: 1867520)
remote:        Error
remote:        at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:2359:10623)
remote:        at js_error (<eval>:2359:10842)
remote:        at croak (<eval>:2359:19086)
remote:        at token_error (<eval>:2359:19223)
remote:        at unexpected (<eval>:2359:19311)
remote:        at expr_atom (<eval>:2359:27526)
remote:        at maybe_unary (<eval>:2359:30019)
remote:        at expr_ops (<eval>:2359:30777)
remote:        at maybe_conditional (<eval>:2359:30869)
remote:        at maybe_assign (<eval>:2359:31312)
remote:        at maybe_assign (<eval>:2359:31486)
remote:        at expression (<eval>:2359:31625)
remote:        at expr_list (<eval>:2359:27830)
remote:        at <eval>:2359:27944
```

Comment: It seems you may have some syntax error in your js file.

Comment: did you try running `rake assets:precompile` locally?